# What do the kernel options in braces mean?

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration

I saw a kernel option today in `menuconfig` that used braces for its checkbox.

```
{*}   Button
```

This isn't listed in the legend at the top of the screen.

```
[*] built-in  [ ] excluded  <M> module  < > module capable
```

What do the braces signify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It represents an option that has been implied to a specific value by another option.

This [Gentoo's wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Configuration/en) has a clear explanation and lists all the available types that `menuconfig` can display. For example: the hyphen is also listed there.